# How to download folder as zip using dropbox Ruby SDK

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dropbox-api

We can get the share link for a dropbox folder from SDK(https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-ruby/blob/master/lib/dropbox_sdk.rb#L1222-L1225), which link is `dl=0` by default, I need to set it with `dl=1` so that it will download directly, I did some hack:

```
require 'dropbox_sdk';
client = DropboxClient.new(ENV['dropbox_access_token'])
session = DropboxOAuth2Session.new(Option['dropbox_access_token'], nil)
response = session.do_get "/shares/auto#{client.format_path('/auction_offerings/two')}", {"short_url" => false}
response = Dropbox::parse_response(response)
response["url"][-1]="1"
```

Then `response["url"]` will become the download link I want, but it is obvious not the right way to do that. Any better practice？

Comment: It would be better to parse the URL and modify the query parameters in a safer way. (E.g., what if Dropbox started returning `?dl=0&something=else` someday?) But the general approach of getting the share link and modifying it is okay.

Comment: @smarx Yep, thanks for your suggestion, will use regular expression to replace the `dl` parameter.